# How to order a grouped collection select

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ok here's my problem. I have a dropdown of subcategories ordered by category. That's cool, but I really need to order subcategories as well. Here's the code in question:

```
<%= grouped_collection_select(:subcategory, :id, Category.order(:name), :populated_subcategories, :name, :id, :name, {}, { :class=> "form-control" }) %>
```

Comment: If you set ordering on the association it should work I think.

`has_many :populated_subcategories,
    -> { order('name') }`

Comment: No problem.  Though that will order it everywhere in your application you do @category.populated_subcategories

Comment: That's what we want so it's ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set ordering on the association it should work I think.

```
has_many :populated_subcategories,     -> { order('name') }
```